# Module 'path_provider' not found

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, module

I have used several times the Xcode simulator for my flutter app.
One time I tried to change the simulator to iPhone 11 Pro (don't know if it did or did not cause the problem) but since then:

1. I get the error Module 'path_provider' not found.
2. It seems that each time when I double click on the Runner.xcworkspace file, it opens the project file instead. I'm new to Xcode so not quite sure about that but I attached a screenshot.

Things I've tried:

- updated according to the instructions in the warnings (which can be seen in the screenshot).
- deleted all Xcode cache with [Reset Xcode](https://gist.github.com/maciekish/66b6deaa7bc979d0a16c50784e16d697)
- deleted the android studio project and popped it again from git.
- flutter clean + removed all the pod files + pod install from android studio terminal.
  according to the explanations here: [reinstall pod](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48103#issuecomment-570463375)

What else can I do?

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: I somehow solved it long time ago, I posted the solution I think it solved for me. Update if it solved for you too

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same issue. All I had to do was open the `runner.xcworkspace` instead of `runner.xcodeproj` and run the app.

Comment: it just worked! :)

Answer (score 9):

I faced this same error and realized that I have used `pod init` manually so I deleted the `Podfile` in the `ios` folder then run `flutter build ios`.
The Flutter will generate the `Podfile` correctly and everything works well after that.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had spent the whole day look for a solution. Yours is the only one that worked for me. I had done Pod Init instead of letting flutter generate it for me.

Answer (score 2):

In Flutter project, I Also faced with this issue. Fixed by updating flutter and cocoa pods to the latest version.

```
flutter clean
rm -Rf ios/Pods
rm -Rf ios/.symlinks
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
flutter pub get
```

- Move to podfile (project_name/ios/Podfile) and comment `platform :ios, '11.0'` like this `# platform :ios, '11.0'`
  then run this commands

```
cd ios
pod install
arch -x86_64 pod install  //(On an M1 mac use => arch -x86_64 pod install)
cd ..
flutter run
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me, as it seems, was that the Xcode opened "Runner.xcodeproj" instead of "Runner.xcworkspace"
from what I understood, .xcworkspace is the one that makes the bindings/connections between files and packages. xcodeproj doesn't do it and that's why it was missin although I did have it.

Solution:
To be sure I do have the updated version of the missing package:

1. cd [project path]
2. Flutter clean (or delete the build folder to ensure there is no cache)
3. cd [project path]/ios
4. pod install
5. pod update

Then, when opening the Xcode I clicked:
Project navigator (folder icon on the left toolbar) -> Runner (in the project tree that opened) -> Runner (under Targets)
(shown in the attached picture)

and then when I build it worked for me.

[image]

Comment: i have perform above steps but still getting same error.

Answer (score 1):

My technique is basically to rip it up and start again - keeping all the lib files though! That way you can keep track of what you need to do to fix the things you broke trying to fix it earlier !

I create a new flutter project and add the lib files from the broken project. then piece by piece put it back together.
I decided on this idea after trawling through many 'patches' to the specific errors that I saw. I should not have been anywhere near those errors - so patching them just broke more - untraceably. Hence the rebuild.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In `Podfile`, I just comment `platform :ios, '11.0'`, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that was caused by the linker.
I solved it as follows:
runner->build setting->other linker flags, and delete path_provider

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue due to google_fonts library. I removed it and it works.