# Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'path_provider_ios' not found

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build

when i am build the flutter app in xcode , i am getting error
"Parse Issue (Xcode): Module 'path_provider_ios' not found"
so could you please provide solution was is missing .

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your Xcode project.
2. Navigate to the "Build Settings" tab.
3. Select the "Linking" category.
4. Look for the "Other Linker Flags" setting and expand it.
5. Find the flag that includes "path_finder_ios".
6. Remove the flag by clicking on it and pressing the delete key, or by right-clicking and selecting "Delete".
7. Save your changes and rebuild your project.

Note that this step is necessary because the "path_provider_ios" package has been discontinued and replaced by "path_provider_foundation". Removing the "path_finder_ios" flag will ensure that your project is not trying to link to the deprecated package and is instead using the new package correctly.

Comment: module 'path_provider_foundation' not found

I'm getting this error when building archive.

flutter build ios working fine via command line.

Answer (score 0):

Do you open "Runner.xworkspace"  ? or "Runner.xcodeproj" ?

Comment: Runner.xworkspace

Comment: you can try this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68000422/17626346

Comment: i have perform above steps but still getting same error.

Comment: Did you solve it now? @jaydev